# Remove an element from array with user input

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with removing items from a Javascript array. I am using a prompt, and when the user inputs a worker's ID number, I want that element to be removed from the array.

At the moment, my code will only remove the final element in the list.

This is my code:

```
var remove = function(){
    var removeID = prompt("Enter ID of the worker you wish to remove: ");
    var index = array.indexOf(removeID);
    if(removeID == id){
        array.splice(index, 1);
        showArray();
    }
    else{
        alert("id is not in the system");
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(removeID == id){` makes no sense

Comment: It's the id of the worker, it has been declared in the rest of the Javascript which is all working perfectly.

Comment: So you are saying if the id they entered only matches that worker, than they can remove it....

Comment: Change `if(removeID == id){` to `if (index >= 0) {` and it will work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up your logic

```
if(removeID == id){
```

should probably be checking to see if the id exists in the array before removing it.

```
if(index !== -1){
```

and another guess since you did not give a runnable example:

```
var removeID = Number(prompt("Enter ID of the worker you wish to remove: "));
```

Comment: I had tried that, but when I do, it doesn't remove anything at all.

Comment: So does the indexOf actually find the entered ID? What is in the actual array? Is it strings or numbers?

Comment: I have just updated my above answer. I think the problem might be that you have integer IDs, whereas prompt() always returns a string. If your array is [1,2,3], then array.indexOf(1) === 0, but array.indexOf('1') === -1.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up array indices with elements. It should go like this:

```
var remove = function(){
    var removeID = prompt("Enter ID of the worker you wish to remove: ");
    var index = array.indexOf(removeID);
    if(index > -1){ // HERE!!!
        array.splice(index, 1);
        showArray();
    }
    else{
        alert("id is not in the system");
    }
}
```

Two additional observations:

- If IDs are numbers, then your call to array.indexOf() will always return -1. prompt() will always give you a string, not an integer; you should use parseInt() instead like this:

  ```
  var removeID = parseInt(prompt("Enter ID of the worker you wish to remove: "));
  ```
- Since IDs are meant to be unique, and depending on the context, it might make sense to store them inside an object rather than an array so that you don't risk having duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dk4kb417/1/

This method should remove the index you want. It will ask for the element value. The first index of that value will be deleted:

```
var array = ['one','two','three',4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var remove = function(removeID){
    var index = array.indexOf(removeID);
    if (index>-1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
remove(prompt("Enter ID of the worker you wish to remove: "));
console.log(array);
```